# how to show data column-wise in rdlc local reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc

I have an WPF application which has a local rdlc report which show receipt based selling of the day. As this query have 4 columns (MemoNo, Gross, Discount, NetSales) and rows more than 1000 so its not a good idea to show data row-wise as it will waste more space per page. Is there any way to show data in column-wise so.

```
MemoNo   Gross    Discount    NetSales    MemoNo   Gross    Discount    NetSales
```

Thanks A Lot...........

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to divide data in multiple columns in tsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173930/how-to-divide-data-in-multiple-columns-in-tsql)

Comment: You should have edited this question instead of making a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Matrix to show data as column wise.