# how to divide data in multiple columns in tsql

Tags: visual-studio-2008, t-sql, rdlc

i have around 1000 of rows in database which i want to divide in column group wise. i mean in following format

```
SlNo.    Name    Price      SlNo.    Name    Price      SlNo.    Name    Price
```

how i can write query to show data in above format as in rdlc report vs 2008 i am unable to show data in this format. Any help would be appreciated...

**Sales Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
[SalesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MemoNo] [int] NULL,
[CustomerID] [int] NULL,
[SalesmanID] [int] NULL,
[DisRate] [int] NULL,
[CoolingCh] [int] NULL,
[GrandTotal] [int] NULL,
[SubTotal] [int] NULL,
[BillDate] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[AddedOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SalesId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

thanks.........

Comment: I don't think that is possible with a SQL query, unless you create a rather complicated stored procedure. These things are better done in code.

Comment: This should be a simple `SELECT (fields) FROM dbo.Sales` and then in Report Designer make your report display the three columns repeated three times across....

Comment: @marc_s: this should be an answer

Comment: but report designer not rendering report as i need even if I make it column-wise. By the way i need output to be first column wise then row wise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a simple

```
SELECT 
    SalesId, [Name], GrandTotal as 'Price'
FROM 
    dbo.Sales 
WHERE
    (some condition)
```

to retrieve all the data you need, and then in the SQL Server Report Designer make your report display the three columns repeated three times across...

Use SQL Server and T-SQL to **retrieve the data**, and use SQL Server Reporting Services to **format the output** to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think something could be done along the lines of...

```
SELECT
    SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT SalesId, Name, Price
                  FROM Sales S2
                  WHERE S2.SalesId = S1.SalesId    ) as Tab1,
    SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT SalesId, Name, Price
                  FROM Sales S2
                  WHERE S2.SalesId = S1.SalesId + 1) as Tab2,
    SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT SalesId, Name, Price
                  FROM Sales S2
                  WHERE S2.SalesId = S1.SalesId + 2) as Tab3
    FROM Sales
    WHERE ...every third row...;
```

I can't fill in the full details because I'm no expert on TSQL, and also the table doesn't contain a SlNo, Name or Price which you presumably have to get from somewhere. Whether that's an improvement on going to code as Ronald Wildenberg suggests is a matter of taste.